# Form name value based on c# variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, input

Is there any way to create the name variable in an input text field with a c# variable in it?

So something like:

```
<input type="text" name="Status + @i" value="" />
```

I tried a few different combinations:

```
name="'Status' + '@i'"
name = "Status" + @i
```

but none of them worked after submitting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use String.Format() :

```
name="@String.Format("Status{0}", i)"
```

or directly

```
name='Status@i'
```

Answer (score 0):

Also

```
@('Status' + i.ToString())
```

OR

```
<input type="text" name="Status@(i)" value="" />
```

I think works too

should work too, String.Format is more flexible, however.

Comment: No need for `ToString` here. If there first element of the concatenation is a string, the rest will be implicitly calling `ToString` (altough, making it explicit is all fine and a matter of taste / succinctness)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="Status_@i" value="" />
```